# Regex for replace the string on particular position

Tags: java, regex

`MSH|^~\&|RAD|MCH|SOARCLIN|MCH|201309281506||ORU^R01|RMS|P|2.4
PID|0001|_MISSING_|059805^a~059805^a~059805^a||RENNER^KATHRYN^`

In a string like the above I need to replace the string on basis of | (pipe sign) count.

e.g.  :

> MSH line want to replace after 3rth position of (|) pipe sign "MCH"
>   with "ABC"
>
> input : MSH|^~\&|RAD|MCH|SOARCLIN|MCH|201309281506||ORU^R01|RMS|P|2.4
>
> output : MSH|^~\&|RAD|MCH|SOARCLIN|ABC|201309281506||ORU^R01|RMS|P|2.4

Comment: We disagree where the 3rd pipe sign is.

Comment: that is example i given. position will be any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String repSection( String del, int count, String rep ){
    String[] toks = theString.split( Pattern.quote( del ) );
    toks[count] = rep;
    theString = String.join( del, toks );
}
```

Call:

```
String result = repSection( "|", 3, "ABC" );
```

It depends on counting alone; it doesn't matter what is there between the 3rd and 4th pipe char.

I prefer this to some fancy and difficult to maintain regex.

```
s = s.replaceAll( "^((?:[^|]*\\|){3})[^|]*", "$1|ABC" );
```

Again, this doesn't care what is between 3rd and 4th pipe symbol.

Comment: hello @laune  : is this possible to replace that pipe seperated content have also some inner seperated content. 
for example:

 PV1|027052^SCHROPP~GUY^M^1^2^MD|O|^1^2^MCH||||027052^SCHROPP~GUY^M^^^MD

so now first occurrence of pipe and inside that content is
027052^SCHROPP~GUY^M^1^2^MD
now first occurrence of ~ separated and content is this:
GUY^M^1^2^MD
inside that ~ separated i have another separated ^ separate 
and need to replace at occurrence of ^ at position 2 : Eg: 1 with K:

Comment: In this situation I would use the split/join approach with a recursive version of repSection and with modified arguments: `repSection( String[] dels, int[]counts, String rep )`.